# Jenkins DSL Plugin: How to create a job in an existing jenkins View?

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I found the following question regarding job creation and adding to a newly created view with the DSL plugin.

[Adding job to newly created view.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021763/create-a-job-dsl-that-creates-a-new-job-in-the-same-view)

How can i add a created job to an existing view with the DSL plugin? I couldn´t find any hint in the documentation. Maybe it is too obvious that i can´t see the solution?

Although i read, that creating a view will cause a re-creation if the view already exists. What means that for the existing projects under this view?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not add a job to a view that is not managed by the Job DSL. But the views managed by the DSL can contain jobs which are not managed by the DSL.

For example you can have a job called `project-a` which is managed manually and a job called `project-b` which is managed by the DSL. And a view managed by the DSL can contain both jobs.

```
job('project-b') {
}

listView('project-view') {
  jobs {
    name('project-a')
    name('project-b')
  }
}
```

It's not possible to use the Jenkins API to add a job to a view from a DSL script. The job has to exist before it can be added to a view. But when the scripts is executed, the job is not created immediately. All DSL items are created after the script has been processed.

If you do not want the manage the view with the DSL (but you should), you can try to use a filter-based view configuration. E.g. include all jobs with a name matching a regular expression. Or you can use the [View Job Filters Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters) to create more complex filters.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will try to use the filter-based view configuration, to sort the DSL created jobs belonging to a specific topic under a view. The thing with the DSL view is; it could be the case, that i want to re-create only a sub-set of the DSL view related jobs, and i´m not sure wheather the re-creation of that view will delete all the already existing DSL jobs in that view, which i really want to keep...

Comment: If you set the "Action for removed jobs" in the settings of the "Process Job DSLs" step to "Ignore", no job will be deleted. And there is a similar setting for views as well.

Comment: I tried it, but it's not working as expected (e.g. the jobs are not put under the view), here is the output:Processing provided DSL script
Added items:
    GeneratedJob{name='project-a'}
    GeneratedJob{name='project-b'}
Unreferenced items:
    GeneratedJob{name='DSL-Dummy2'}
Removed items:
    GeneratedJob{name='DSL-Dummy2'}
Added views:
    GeneratedView{name='project-view'}
Finished: SUCCESS

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to daspilker, with your provided details I found an acceptable solution.

-> The view filters

Requirements: [View Job Filter PLugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/View+Job+Filters)

Since DSL created jobs can´t be added to non-DSL created views, I set two view filters.

- one regexp view filter to exclude the DSL created jobs from the default view (where the jobs would be created if you do not create a DSL view and add the job to it) - select the default view->Edit View->Add Job Filter->regexpJobFilter
- one regexp view filter on the view, where you want to collect the DSL created jobs.

For now, this works fine. I have DSL created jobs in a manually managed view.

But as daspilker says:

> If you do not want the manage the view with the DSL (**but you should**)

Maybe the experience shows, that i have to switch to the DSL managed views.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found a very simple workaround to this problem - although we should keep in mind that @daspilker's answer shows the correct way of managing jobs and views. Just that it was too complicated for me at this time (or been too lazy).

#### Workaround:

- delete the job generated by your DSL
- copy (or remember) the *exact* name of the generated job from the DSL
- go to the view where you want the new job to reside in
- create a new empty job with the *same* name as the new generated job from the DSL.
- check *Add to current view* when saving the new empty job
- run the DSL script and it will update your existing (empty) job with the correct content while leaving it in the desired view.

I just came to this solution while remembering that I once deleted (overwritten) an existing job from a view by running a DSL job with the same target name, but at least it stayed in the original view :)